# No consigo que el bucle for pase de la segunda posición del array para rellenarlo y posteriormente imprirlo con un alert con Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for

Estoy realizando un ejercicio en el que quiero recorrer un array ingresando un nombre (hasta 11) para que me devuelva el dorsal, nombre y la posición (ej: 1-Juan-Portero) del equipo entero en una lista.

Tras ingresar el nombre en la primera posición, me pide la segunda y luego me vuelve a pedir la segunda hasta el infinito sin conseguir salir del bucle.

Código:

```
var jugadores = new Array ();

for(let i=0; i<11; i++){
    let nombre = prompt("Introduce el nombre del jugador con el dorsal "+[i+1]);

    if(i=0){
        jugadores.push((i+1)+" - "+nombre+" - "+"Portero"+"\n");
    }    
        
    else if(i>=1 && i<=4){
        jugadores.push((i+1)+" - "+nombre+" - "+"Defensa"+"\n");
    }
    else if(i>=5 && i<=7){
        jugadores.push((i+1)+" - "+nombre+" - "+"Medio"+"\n");
    }
    
    else if(i>7 && i<11){
        jugadores.push((i+1)+" - "+nombre+" - "+"Delantero"+"\n");
    }
        
}

alert(jugadores) ;
```

Agradecería que me pudiérais indicar dónde está el error. También, si hay una manera mas facil de plantearlo me vendría bien, aunque ya que he tirado por aquí me gustaría resolverlo.

Gracias

Comment: Antes de leer todo tu código: en el primer `if` estás asignando en lugar de comparar. ¿Es correcto?

Comment: si, en el caso de que i=0   es el unico caso en el que tiene que entrar en ese if

Comment: `i==0`: comparar. `i=0`: asignar.

Comment: Claro! Los basicos me patinan aún... vuelta al manual.. GRACIAS!